# Why is Golang's http.DefaultClient exported?

Tags: http, go, client

I'm curious about why the variable `var DefaultClient` in Go's `http` package is exported. As the comment of the variable suggests, it is used internally by methods such as Get(). If that is the case, why does it have to be exported?

When I first started coding HTTP related stuff, I always thought I could just use the `DefaultClient` to send all my requests, until I found out it is not a function that returns a new `Client` every time, but more like a static pointer variable that always points to the same empty `Client` instance... so if I decided to modify its properties, all subsequent calls with the DefaultClient will be affected.

Again, what's purpose of exporting this variable?

Comment: Isn't that the whole point of exporting it? That you can modify it, and then all the other methods that use it uses the modified client.

Comment: It is exported to be usable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't speak definitively (as I didn't design the package), but if it's exported, it can be modified. This means you can set the timeout etc (which isn't specified by default).

Convenience methods like `http.Get` are just a wrapper around `DefaultClient.Get`, it would make sense to be able to modify the timeout of `DefaultClient` beforehand, but to perhaps use all the other defaults - such as the ability to reuse connections/transports.